# take a sample from a data frame in r proportionate with binary outcome

Tags: r, binary, sampling

I Have a data frame which includes a binary outcome plus other variables.
i want to take a sample of size n form this data but i want to see the same proportion of response in the sample.
for example if the response has %60 of '1' and %40 of '0' in the original data, then i want to see the same proportion in the sampled file of size n. A mocked data is below with same proportions.

```
    response<- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
    x <- c(11,34,23,45,77,8,9,87,32,56)
    data <- data.frame(response,x)
```

Comment: see `?sample` there is a probability weighting argument named `prob`.

Comment: `sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.4, .6))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidyverse approach using `dplyr::sapmle_frac` and `purrr::map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% group_by(response) %>% mutate(grb=n()/nrow(.)) %>% #Get precentage for each response
         group_by(response,grb) %>% nest() %>% #Group by res and grb then do nesting
         mutate(samp = map2(data, grb, sample_frac))  %>% 
         select(response, samp) %>%
         unnest()
```